# UrlRewritting affect ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, url-rewriting, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using UrlRewritting in my project. all functionality is working proper but I cant use the ASP.NET Ajax like updatePanel etc. the problem is ScriptResource.axd file is missing (404 Error). I used lot of ASP.net Ajax control before using UrlRewritting so I cant change the whole code.....

1. how can I enable ASP.NET Ajax?
2. have any Alternative to replace ASP.NET Ajax without changing in codebehind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure the URL Rewriting module in web.config file.

Negate all .axd or .svc or any or any jquery or webservice request or any specif file or URL.

For example..

```
<rule name="Lower Case URLs" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="ScriptResource.axd" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="CIMService.svc" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Trailing Slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])$"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="ScriptResource.axd" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="CIMService.svc" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/"/>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule that explicitly avoids blocking or re-routing all .axd files.

An MVC project for example has this specific route exception:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

This ensures Ajax (among other things) works correctly.